# Wrap legend text in altair

Tags: python, altair

I have the following example where I'm trying to plot 4 points. When I wrap the text for the point legend labels the result is only 1 point for each category (2 points total).

Any help figuring out how to wrap legend text without losing data would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import textwrap

# Example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'point': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   'label': ['My super long label that is too long',
                             'Short label',
                             'My super long label that is too long',
                             'Short label'],
                    'x': [1,2,3,4],
                    'y': [1,2,3,4]})

# Wrap text in the 'label' column
df['label_wrapped'] = df['label'].apply(textwrap.wrap, args=[15])

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    color=alt.Color('label_wrapped:N', title='Label'),
)
chart
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution by using the `labelExpr`

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import textwrap

# Example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'point': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   'label': ['My super long label that is too long',
                             'Short label',
                             'My super long label that is too long',
                             'Short label'],
                    'x': [1,2,3,4],
                    'y': [1,2,3,4]})

# Wrap text in the 'label' column
df["label_wrapped"] = df["label"].apply(lambda x: "|".join(textwrap.wrap(x, width=15)))

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    color=alt.Color('label_wrapped:N',
                    title='Label',
                    legend=alt.Legend(labelExpr="split(datum.label, '|')")),
    tooltip=[
        alt.Tooltip("label", title="name"),
        alt.Tooltip("point")
    ],
)
chart
```

[image]